# row-clicked, row-dblclicked works fine in my b-table, but row-contextmenu event doesn't work.Is there anything else to do to get it fine?

Tags: bootstrap-vue

In my vue project Iam using bootstrap vue datatable.Row-clicked, row-dblclicked events works fine in my b-table, but row-contextmenu event doesn't work.Is there anything else to do to get it fine???

Answer (score 2):

here's a very simple JSFiddle which hopefully shows how you can use the `row-contextmenu` event in a Bootstrap-Vue `<b-table>`:

https://jsfiddle.net/adlaws/84onvtam/

There's not much to it, as you can see. Basically your table definition looks like this:

```
<b-table 
     :items="items"
     @row-contextmenu="handleContextMenuEvent">
</b-table>
```

...and the JavaScript handler function (in the `methods` section) looks like this:

```
handleContextMenuEvent(item, index, event)
  {
    // stop browser context menu from appearing
    event.preventDefault();
    // log the selected item to the console
    console.log(item);
  }
```

In the JSFiddle you should see console logging output each time you right-click an item.

I hope that helps!